# Get all minor versions of a list or library using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I need to get information about all the minor versions of a specific list or library using REST API. I tried it with

```
'_api/web/getchanges'
```

But it didn't get what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code . I hope , u will get your required Output.

```
function getMinorVersion() {
        var getfilename = document.getElementById("getfilename").value;
        var executor;

        // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
        executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Shared%20Documents/FolderA')/files('" + getfilename + "')/MinorVersion?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: getMinorVersionSuccessHandler,
            error: getMinorVersionErrorHandler
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It does not seem possible to get versions for a `List Item` via REST/CSOM APIs, but there are alternative options

**Using Versions.aspx application page**

The idea is to perform a get request to Versions page:

```
http://{server}/{site}/_layouts/versions.aspx?list={litsID}&ID={itemID}
```

**Code**:

```
function getItemVersions(url,listId,itemId,success)
{
   var versionsUrl = url + '/_layouts/versions.aspx?list=' + listId + '&ID=' + itemId;  
   $.get( versionsUrl, function( data ) {
      var versionEntries = parseVersionList(data);
      success(versionEntries);
   });
}


function parseVersionList(data){
   var entries = {};
   var versionList = $(data).find('table.ms-settingsframe');


   versionList.find('tbody > tr').each(function(i){
     if(i > 0 && (i-1) % 2 == 0) {
        var verRow = $(this); //get version row
        var propsRow = verRow.next(); //get properties row
        var versionLabel = verRow.find('td:first').html().trim();
        entries[versionLabel] = {};
        //extract item properties from propsRow goes here
        //...
     }

   });   
   return entries;
}


//Usage
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
var listItemId = 1;
getItemVersions(webUrl,listId,listItemId,function(versionEntries){
  console.log(versionEntries);
});
```

Now from the above code, you can differentiate the minor versions inside `parseVersionList` function.

Comment: what about the CORS? I get CORs error using this code in a provider hosted app. Is it possible?